# Разбить сайт на город вида https://site.ru/omsk и т.д. (https://site.ru/omsk/page1, https://site.ru/omsk/page2)

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, url, site

Есть сайт https://site.ru у него есть директории рабочие

- https://site.ru/page1
- https://site.ru/page2/action1
  и т.д.

Нужно разбить на города (Найти информацию не смогла...).

Вот так:

- https://site.ru/omsk/page1
- https://site.ru/omsk/page2/action1
  и т.д.

т.е. добавление /$1 - не влияет на функционал, как это сделать?

Comment: ссылки поменяйте) что за сайт, какой движок? больше инфы

Answer (score 0):

в любом фреймворке/cms есть так называемый `UrlManager`. И он настраивается легко под подобные нужды. Пока вы не написали на чём конкретно стоит сайт, сложно вам чем-то больше помочь